# Error when trying to evaluate `coprime`

Tags: isabelle

I want to use the `coprime` function that is defined in Isabelle's `GCD` and play a bit around with it.
Why does `value "coprime Suc(Suc 0) Suc(Suc(Suc (Suc 0)))"` return the error

```
Type unification failed: No type arity fun :: gcd

Type error in application: incompatible operand type

Operator:  coprime :: ??'a ⇒ ??'a ⇒ bool
Operand:   Suc :: nat ⇒ nat

Coercion Inference:

Local coercion insertion on the operand failed:
No type arity fun :: gcd

Now trying to infer coercions globally.

Coercion inference failed:
weak unification of subtype constraints fails
Clash of types "_ ⇒ _" and "nat"
```

instead of `false` ?

(This is also the case for `value "coprime 0 0"`.)

---

A minimal MWE w.r.t the answer:

```
(*<*) theory T
  imports   
 Main
"~~/src/HOL/Number_Theory/Number_Theory"
begin (*>*)

value "coprime 2 (4 :: nat))"

(*<*) end (*>*)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues here.

1. It should be `value "coprime (Suc(Suc 0)) (Suc(Suc(Suc (Suc 0))))"`. Function application binds strongest and associates to the left, so what you wrote would be interpreted as `coprime` applied to `Suc`, `Suc 0`, and some other arguments, which is a type error.
2. `coprime 0 0` works out fine in my version of Isabelle; it outputs the somewhat confusing `"equal_class.equal (gcd 0 0) 1" :: "bool"`. The reason for this is that there is nothing in that term to indicate that the `0` is a natural number, and evaluation of polymorphic constants tends to be problematic. Even something like `2 ≠ 4` will not evaluate to `True` in general because this depends on what type `2` and `4` have. If you write `coprime 0 (0::nat)`, everything works as expected.

Additionally, it would be more convenient to write `value "coprime 2 (4 :: nat)` instead of using the successor notation.

Comment: As always, thanks a lot for your response. I wouldn't know, what to do without your fast responses. Though `value "coprime 2 (4 :: nat)"` doesn't compile for me, as it says `Inner syntax error⌂
Failed to parse term`. I put a minimal (non)working example in my answer as an edit.

Comment: You seem to have an unclosed bracket in your MWE - possibly that is the problem?

Comment: `value "coprime 2 (4 :: nat)"` should *absolutely* work. The extra parenthesis IIM pointed out would, on the other hand, lead to that exact error.